How to invoke corresponding macro based on the number of arguments including empty arguments
I want a macro that generate a function based on the parameters.
such as EXPAND_FUNC(func, int).
generated:
void func(int value)
{
    _func(value);
}

Below is the implementation.
#define CONCAT_(a, b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_(a, b)

#define EXPAND(x) x
#define ARG_N(...) EXPAND(NARG(__VA_ARGS__, RSEQN()))
#define NARG(...) EXPAND(ARG_N_(__VA_ARGS__))

#define ARG_N_(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, N, ...) N
#define RSEQN() 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
#define GET_MACRO(func, ...) CONCAT(func, EXPAND(ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define COMPOSE(name, ...) EXPAND(name(__VA_ARGS__))

#define PARAMS(...) COMPOSE(GET_MACRO(PARAMS_, __VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

#define PARAMS_0()
#define PARAMS_1(A) A a
#define PARAMS_2(A, B) A a, B b
#define PARAMS_3(A, B, C) A a, B b, C c
#define PARAMS_4(A, B, C, D) A a, B b, C c, D d
#define PARAMS_5(A, B, C, D, E) A a, B b, C c, D d, E e
#define PARAMS_6(A, B, C, D, E, F) A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f

#define ARGS(...) COMPOSE(GET_MACRO(ARGS_, __VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

#define ARGS_0()
#define ARGS_1(A) a
#define ARGS_2(A, B) a, b
#define ARGS_3(A, B, C) a, b, c
#define ARGS_4(A, B, C, D) a, b, c, d
#define ARGS_5(A, B, C, D, E) a, b, c, d, e
#define ARGS_6(A, B, C, D, E, F) a, b, c, d, e, f

#define EXPAND_FUNC(name, ...) \
    void name(PARAMS(__VA_ARGS__)) \
    { \
        _##name(ARGS(__VA_ARGS__));\
    }

EXPAND_FUNC works for one or more parameter lists but doesn't work for empty parameters.
EXPAND_FUNC(func0) will be expanded as
void func0(a)
{
    _func0(a);
}

How to make EXPAND_FUNC(func0) work.

When your macros start to look like these do, then it's time to stop and rethink. Perhaps it's a problem with the design? Perhaps with the implementation of that design? Never the less, the solution to almost all problems with macros are functions. Or in your case perhaps a custom preprocessor that runs as part of the build-process to automatically create the functions you need, without the use of macros.

Also, unlike macros, functions can be overloaded on number of arguments, so func(a) and func(a, b) is just fine. You don't need to generate unique names.

Please be aware that macros are more like a C feature. In C++ they should be avoided as much as possible. Most of the problem can be resolved using templates, the number of cases where macro is unavoidable are quite limited. For that reason you should explain what is your actual goal not ask "how to fix your current solution with a macros".

Please forget macros for now, and restate your problem. Why do you want to generate such simple function in the first place ? Your macro arg looks like a template type, why not:
template< typename T> void func( T arg ) { ... } ?

The scenario is that There is many interfaces in a class A:
class A{
void func0();
void func1(int);
}

and for some reaon, I need dispatch some of them to a thread and don't modify their signature.
I know macros is ugly solution, but I don't know better one.

lambdas might be what you need, [/*..*/](/*..*/){ return func0(); }

Ok, so you have:
struct A {
    void func0();
    void func1(int);
};

A some_a;

and you want to dispatch calls to A::func0, ... in a separate thread pool/executor.
The simplest (but not the most efficient) would be to use std::async
// note : you need to guarantee the scope of some_a
std::async( &A::func0, &some_a );
std::async( &A::func1, &some_a, 42 );

You can also have a simple executor which takes a std::function:
struct MyExecutor
{
    void submit( std::function< void()> fn ) { ... }
};

And invoke it via:
MyExecutor exec; // or provided somewhere
exec.submit( []{ some_a.func0(); } ); // if some_a is global, otherwise capture it
exec.submit( []{ some_a.func1( 42 ); } );

I hope you have some knowledge of multithreading, concurrency and understand objects lifetime and scopes...

In macro, empty argument is an argument.
so use extra dummy argument and use __VA_OPT__ (C++20)
#define ARGS(...) COMPOSE(GET_MACRO(ARGS_ __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

#define ARGS_1(dummy)
#define ARGS_2(dummy, A) a
#define ARGS_3(dummy, A, B) a, b
#define ARGS_4(dummy, A, B, C) a, b, c
#define ARGS_5(dummy, A, B, C, D) a, b, c, d
#define ARGS_6(dummy, A, B, C, D, E) a, b, c, d, e
#define ARGS_7(dummy, A, B, C, D, E, F) a, b, c, d, e, f

#define EXPAND_FUNC(name, ...) \
    void name(PARAMS(dummy __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)) \
    { \
        _##name(ARGS(dummy __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__));\
    }

Demo
You might probably want to change COMPOSE instead. Left as exercice :-)

Please stop dropping more ugly macros here !
We know that the solution to user28234794's XY-problem involves macros, but we don't really know his real problem !
In modern C++, macros should only be considered as a last-resort solution, only after having weighted all other possibilities... And very rarely they are the best solution.

@Steve Macros are perfectly fine for generating cumbersome boilerplate code. If a question is asking how to do X then tell them how to do X (or say it cannot be done if that is the case), and only then propose alternatives to X (bringing up the XY-problem). Stop shaming real answers for answering how to do X when that is exactly what the question is asking, and rather supplement with alternatives if there are none given in the answer.

No. Macros are only fine if you don't have a better solution. Even the user says : "I know macros is ugly solution, but I don't know better one. "

@Steve: Shown PARAM_1, .., PARAM_N pattern exists BTW, handling PARAM_0 as question seems legitimate to me (even if it is in reality an XY problem as shown from comment, and not from post/question).
